# How to make automatic indexing in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

Now I do indexing via command in linux(CentOS 6.5) terminal:

```
indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --all --rotate
```

How I can do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with cron, so just re-index periodically. 
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sphinx+search+crontab

But depending on your application, data may only update at specific times, in which case may be better to just trigger a reindex when needed.